# Discord Bot: I want to send random quotes from zenquotes.io, but the code does not produce anything nor do I get an error

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, bots

```
async def get_quote():
    async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
        async with session.get("https://zenquotes.io/api/random") as response:
            json_data = json.loads(response.text)
            quote = json_data[0]["q"]
            return (quote) 

@client.command(aliases=["wow"])
async def inspire(ctx):
    quote = await get_quote()
    await ctx.send(quote)
```

I was told to use aiohttp instead of requests module, so I did. Then when I used aiohttp, it said module 'aiohttp' has no attribute 'get'. So this is my final code right now. Please help.

Comment: I don't think that site (`zenquotes.io`) is working at all.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`response.text` is an async function, not an attribute, so it must be called and awaited. Try:

```py
async def get_quote():
    async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
        async with session.get("https://zenquotes.io/api/random") as response:
            json_data = json.loads(await response.text())
            quote = json_data[0]["q"]
            return quote
```

Answer (score 0):

I used requests.

```
import requests

@bot.command()
async def quote(ctx):
    response = requests.get('https://api.quotable.io/random')
    r = response.json()
    await ctx.send(r["content"])
```

This works fine for me.

Comment: requests is not suitable for async environments such as discord bots.

Comment: or just use aiohttp

Answer (score -1):

> please install the package aiohttp and import that one

```
pip3 install aiohttp

import aiohttp
```

*Please refer the first example from this link [docs.aiohttp.org](https://docs.aiohttp.org/en/stable/client_reference.html)*

> install httpx

```
pip3 install httpx
```

> for stater test this one

```
import asyncio
import httpx
async def test():
    async with httpx.AsyncClient() as client:
        resp = await client.get('https://dog.ceo/api/breeds/image/random')
        print(resp)

asyncio.run(test())
```

Comment: aiohttp is already on python lib folder though

Comment: ok. but that site zenquotes.io is not working

Comment: so should I use another api?

Comment: Can you please check with another API and check the status code that you are getting some response or not . try this link -> https://apipheny.io/free-api/#apis-without-key

Comment: I used this link: https://rapidapi.com/andruxnet/api/random-famous-quotes/
and got this error: discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: HTTPException: 400 Bad Request (error code: 50006): Cannot send an empty message

Comment: there is a httpx module in python. you can use that one as well .

Comment: Your code cannot get any quote, that's why it says cannot send an empty message. So the API is broken, use some other API